# Official OSX client for Twitter, https?

Tags: macos, applications, twitter

Does the official OSX client for Twitter (the one available in the App Store) use https? I'm unable to find any info about this on the Twitter site and my searches aren't turning up much either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) says yes, the Twitter OSX client is using https.

> 199.59.148.139    TLSv1   Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done

I did not check if it has anything to do with the [https account settings](https://twitter.com/settings/account), so it might use http if you didn't opt-in for https.